# WPF DesignTime Support for generated control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to build a control or a style that will take care of the usual "label on the left, control on the right" situation. The label column should be same width for all labels.

My ultimate goal is to have a syntax something like this:

```
<l:LayoutGroup>
    <TextBox  l:LabelHelper.Label="111" />
    <ComboBox l:LabelHelper.Label="Nice Box" ItemsSource="{Binding list}"/>
    <ComboBox />
    <Calendar l:LabelHelper.Label="Nice Calendar" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <TextBox l:LabelHelper.Label="eyyoo"/>
</l:LayoutGroup>
```

I actually got this working in 2 different ways. But both do not offer design time support.
The shortest / best setup i could come up with that **does** offer designtime support is the following:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <l:LayoutItem Title="cool textbox">
        <TextBox />
    </l:LayoutItem>
    <l:LayoutItem Title="short">
        <TextBox />
    </l:LayoutItem>
    <l:LayoutItem Title="ye">
        <ComboBox />
    </l:LayoutItem>
</StackPanel>
```

A LayoutItem is a usercontrol with as the following content:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" SharedSizeGroup="Whatever"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="{Binding Path=Title}"/>
    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Child"}/>
</Grid>
```

So its essentially just a bunch of grids, with exactly one child and a shared sizegroup.

What i do to get my goal version to work:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Label",
    typeof(string), typeof(LabelHelper), new UIPropertyMetadata("", Callback));

private static void Callback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var child = d as Control;
    var parent = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
    if (!(parent is StackPanel pnl))
        return;

    pnl.Children.Remove(child);

    var wrapper = new LayoutItem
    {
        Title = GetLabel(child),
        Child = child
    };

    pnl.Children.Add(wrapper);
}

public static string GetLabel(DependencyObject d) => (string)d.GetValue(LabelProperty);
public static void SetLabel(DependencyObject d, string value) => d.SetValue(LabelProperty, value);
```

I take whatever control has the attached property, remove it, wrap it in a layoutitem and add that layoutitem instead.

It works, but there is no designtime support. And i see why its difficult for the designer to support this. I'm creating a different control "at runtime", but its not really runtime, because i noticed that this "Callback" method **does** update the designtime view, if its not too complicated...

Is there any way to get my desired Syntax to work? I feel very close, but all approaches either add a Textblock, a grid, anything to the logical tree that isn't actually in xaml at designtime. That seems to be the main problem and i dont know if its solvable?

I just realized there almost is desintime support now. It works when i add a new Control with the LabelHelper. It just does not adjust if i change the longest label. So the Callback fires in design time, but something isnt quite right.